# Add new light attaches to floor plane

Tags: objects, lighting

I have the newest Blender and have a scene I created, and which has a plane used as a terrain. When I add a light which enters at the center, the light attaches to the plane so when I move the light the plane moves with it. And yes, the plane is not selected when I add the light. I was not sure what to search for to solve this problem. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Ok I went back into Blender and played around with the file and found out I had Proportional Editing switched on. Not sure why it would pull on the ground plane but it did. Turning it off solved the problem.

Comment: It pulls on the ground plane because that's what proportional editing does - affect everything that's within the size of the proportional falloff radius. When in _Edit Mode_, this is limited to the mesh you are editing. When in _Object Mode_ (which you were when adding a light, I guess) it affects all objects which origins are within the proportional editing range.